# Поймать wireshark'ом данные, передаваемые локально

Tags: сеть, wireshark

Допустим, одна тестовая программа передает сообщение другой тестовой программе через сокеты ( используется IP этого компьютера и разные порты).

Как wiresharkom увидеть эти пакеты?
Платформа win7 professional.

Comment: ОС какая? Для винды встроенный в wireshark софт для отлова пакетов не умеет их ловить для localhost'а.

Comment: @владимир , да, win7... Вообще никак?

Comment: вообще, по-моему, он захватывает пакеты и сам, без дополнительных танцев... Но в частности, можно проверить, находитесь ли вы в promiscous mode; еще вариант, но уже более слабый (опять же, если не ошибаюсь) на windows пакеты могут не выходить на уровень сетевых интерфейсов, если система "поняла", что предназначены они для localhost. Последнее можно проверить при помощи виртуализации.

Comment: видимо мысль витала в воздухе...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winpcap, который идет в составе Wireshark не умеет ловить данные с loopback-интерфейса, вот в чем причина. Решение - установка альтернативных средств захвата пакетов, например RawCap. Подробнее - по ссылке https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback